# Return last value of While function

Tags: procedural-programming, infinite-loop, products

I want to make a function that performs a multiplication with `Inner` `i` number of times using a `While` function. Concretely, I have attempted to do:

```
productt[i_, l_] := {m = 1, lastt = t[l]; 
  While[m < (2 i), lastt = Inner[CenterDot, t[l], lastt, Plus]]; m++; 
  lastt}
```

However, it returns this for `i=0`:

```
MatrixForm[{1, {{0, Subscript[t, 1, 2], Subscript[t, 1, 3]}, 
       {-Subscript[t, 1, 2], 0, Subscript[t, 2, 3]},
       {-Subscript[t, 1, 3], -Subscript[t, 2, 3], 0}}}]
```

And for `i=1` it crashes. Essentially I only want the last value of `lastt` to be returned by the function, which is a matrix. I do not want arrays of matrices or anything like that. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `Nest` does precisely this.

Comment: Curly braces and semicolons don't work exactly the same in Mathematica as in C (or whereever you're coming from).

Comment: What should it return for $i=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the `m++` inside the `While`, and properly define a [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html), you're almost there:

```
productt[i_, l_] := Module[{m = 1, lastt = t[l]},
  While[m < 2 i, lastt = Inner[CenterDot, t[l], lastt, Plus]; m++];
  lastt]
```

However this kind of iteration is better done with [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html):

```
productt[i_, l_] := Nest[Inner[CenterDot, t[l], #, Plus] &, t[l], 2 i - 1]
```